# Непонятен синтаксис в строке присваивания кода на PHP

Tags: php, форма, синтаксис

Основная суть данной задачи - это генерация элементов простой html-формы посредством использования интерфейса самой формы (т.е. с использованием чекбоксов, различных полей и т.д.). Ниже представлен учебный и исправный скрипт на PHP. В настоящее время я обучаюсь и в некоторых моментах существует непонимание.

**Страница формы task_form.html.** Тут вопросов нет.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Интерфейс формы</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="formfortask" action="ask_names.php">
<h3>Создать элемент "строка ввода текста":</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="string"><br>
<h3>Количество элементов:</h3>
<input type="text" name="numbers[string]" size="3"><br><br>
<h3>Создать элемент "текстовая область":</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="text"><br>
<h3>Количество элементов:</h3>
<input type="text" name="numbers[text]" size="3"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Создать">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Страница ask_names.php.** Скрипт здесь запрашивает названия элементов формы, которая специфицирована тут - task_form.html.

```
<?php 
echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>"; 
$file = "task.php"; // файл, который будет обрабатывать сгенерированную этим скриптом форму 
function Ask_names() {
    // функция генерирует форму для ввода названий элементов ввода 
    global $file; // объявляем переменную $file глобальной и будем ее использовать в функции 
    if (isset($_GET["types"])) {
        $st = '<form action="'.$file.'">'; 
        foreach ($_GET["types"] as $k => $type) {
            $num = $_GET["numbers"][$type]; 
            for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
                $st .= "Введите имя $i-го элемента типа $type: "; 
                $st .= "<input type='text' name=names[$type][]><br>"; 
            }
            $st .= "<input type='hidden' name='types[]' value='$type'>";
            $st .= "<input type='hidden' name='numbers[]' value='$num'><br>"; 
        }
        $st .= "<input type='submit' name='send' value='Send'></form>";
        return $st; 
    }
    else {
        echo "Select type";
    }
}
echo Ask_names(); 


?>
```

**Здесь есть кое-какое непонимание.**

**1.** В строке 10, где переменная `$num` инициализируется. Что означает эта конструкция,в правой части - `$num = $_GET["numbers"][$type];`? Без этого - `[$type];` ясно, что переменная `$num` получает определенное значение (а точнее - целое число). А что указывает именно `[$type];`. И что в итоге присваивается переменной `$num` ?

**2.** Кроме того, в строке - `$st .= "<input type='text' name=names[$type][]><br>";` , после `name=names[$type]` стоят пустые квадратные скобки, зачем они необходимы? Может это опечатка...

**Страница task.php.** Здесь скрипт непосредственно генерирует форму в зависимости от ее типа и имени.

```
<?php 
echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>"; 
$show_file = "task_show.php"; // этот файл для обработки данных, созданных этим файлом формы 
function Create_element($type, $name) {
    // функция создает элемент ввода по типу и названию 
    $str = ""; 
    switch ($type) {
        case "string": 
         $str .= "$name: <input type='text' name='string[]'><br>"; 
         break;
        case "text":
         $str .= "$name: <textarea name='text[]'></textarea><br>"; 
         break;
    }
    return $str; 
}
function Create_form() {
    // функция создает форму с нужными элементами 
    global $show_file; 
    $str = '<form action="'.$show_file.'">'; 
    foreach ($_GET["types"] as $k => $type) {
        // перебираем типы элементов 
        $num = $_GET["numbers"][$k]; // число элементов этого типа 
        for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
            $arr = $_GET["names"][$type][$i-1]; // имя создаваемого элемента 
            $str .= Create_element($type, $arr); // вызываем функцию для создания элемента 
        }
    }
    $str .= "<input type='submit' value='Send'></form>"; 
    echo $str;
}
$crt = "Create_form"; 
$crt(); //вызываем функцию создания формы Create_form 
?>
```

**3.** Здесь аналогичный вопрос, который был связан с присвоением переменной `$num` непонятного выражения. В данном случае похожее выражение находится в строках:  `$num = $_GET["numbers"][$k];` и `$arr = $_GET["names"][$type][$i-1];`. Как интерпретировать выражения, которые были присвоены переменным `$num` и `$arr`соответственно?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 6):

1. > `$num = $_GET["numbers"][$type];`

`$type` – переменная, по которой достается элемент в массиве `$_GET["numbers"]`

2. > `"<input type='text' name=names[$type][]><br>"`

Квадратные скобки нужны в HTML для передачи в запросе несколько значений. При разборе в PHP это будет массив

3. > Здесь аналогичный вопрос

Аналогичный ответ в пункте 1.

А вы PHP вообще изучали?

### Дополнение

`$_GET["names"][$type][$i-1]` это получения значений по индексу и поскольку цикл начинается с `$i=1`, а индексный массив с `0`, то `[$i-1]` это получение последовательно всех значений

Comment: Получается, в данном случае там, где квадратные скобки, после   `[$type]`, передается еще несколько значений, что в этом примере означает - передается массив имен для каждого конкретного типа элемента?

Comment: @Рустам, там где в HTML квадратные скобки в атрибуте `name` это означает множественное значение, то есть в PHP скрипте вам придет не 1 значение, а индексный массив значений

Comment: это понятно, что в скрипте передается таким образом массив. Но в данном случае отсюда - `$_GET["names"][$type][$i-1];`, выражение `[$i-1]` что показывает? Какую логику оно привносит? Например, я  совсем удалил это выражение `[$i-1]` из кода, и в результате получил название элементов, равное `Array`. То есть в данном случае, `[$i-1]` является индексом значений имен?

Comment: @Рустам да, `$_GET["names"][$type][$i-1]` это получения значений по индексу и поскольку цикл начинается с `$i=1`, а индексный массив с 0, то `[$i-1]` это получение последовательно всех значений

Comment: @Рустам если ответ вас устраивает, слева есть кнопка для отметки ответа как правильного

Comment: пожалуйста, посмотрите в документ task.php. В строке `$num = $_GET["numbers"][$k];`, почему вместо переменной `[$type]` используется переменная-индекс`[$k]`, ведь по сути передается одно и то же значение в переменную `$num`?